# Creating another sheet in work book

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to get a `Excel` work book created using the `Excel-Interop`.
I have one sheet called MonthlyBreakdowns where the values are populated from Dataset. What I want now is to populate another sheet called Template with certain values from the MonthlyBreakdowns sheet.

I have tried these 2, but they do not seem to give me the necessary result.

```
CType(TempWorksheet.Cells(2, 2), Excel.Range).Formula = String.Concat("=VLOOKUP(", """", "010", """", ";MonthlyBreakdown!A1:E143;5;FALSE)")

CType(TempWorksheet.Cells(2, 2), Excel.Range).Value = String.Concat("=VLOOKUP(", """", "010", """", ";MonthlyBreakdown!A1:E143;5;FALSE)")
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not an excel expert, I would suggest that you perfect your excel spreadsheet manually first.

Then, once you know what data you want to appear on sheet2, you can then modify your formula and value above so that it works.

A properly formatted VLOOKUP to get data from another sheet looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP("c", Sheet1!B3:C7, 2)
```

If the problem isn't that your formula is incorrect, there might be a problem with the cell format, but all of this should be able to be fixed manually, and once you figure out how to fix the excel spreadsheet manually, you can then implement that in your code.